# The Difference Using Java and Hadoop Types in Hive UDF

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, udf

When writing a simple Hive UDF, it is possible to use both standard Java and Hadoop types in your `evaluate()` method.  For example, the following methods should return the same results.

Using String input and output types:

```
public String evaluate(String input) {
  if(input == null) return null;
  return input.toUpperCase();
}
```

Using Text input and output types:

```
public Text evaluate(Text input) {
  if(input == null) return null;
  return new Text(input.toString().toUpperCase());
}
```

My question is what are the benefits of using one vs the other?  If I use standard Java input and output types (like String) is Hadoop simply converting these objects to Hadoop types for me?

Comment: I believe the Hadoop values serialize more properly within the context of the MapReduce methods